# Create a resource which will not fetch the backend API on start

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

On react-admin each time we create a resource List , it fetch the API before to render. Is it possible to have a Component that will not fetch on start the API but instead use the fetch call inside ComponentdidMount ?

Comment: Yes it is possible...

Comment: Can you give me an example ?